# How can I found the right Data of Control Group and Treatment Group from any Dataset using SQL, Can anyone tell me please?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

- I have been given to get the 2 types of user from a table called "users" in a dataset.
- The table "users" contains the columns named id, country, gander.
- There are another table named "groups" which contains columns of uid, group, join_dt, device.

Not my question is, which query I need to use to get the result of "treatment group" and "control group"?

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as user_count
FROM users
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY user_count;
```

This code is giving me the count of all the users, but I need the 2 different groups of users called "control_group" and "treatment_group".

I need to know which code I need to use in order to get these two group?
Thanks!